# How do I make an eth1 IP of an instance communicate to eth1 IP of an other instance in a different subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have spun up three instances in 3 AZs in an AWS region. Since they are different AZs these instances are in a different subnet. I have an eth1 interface for all 3 instances. I want my application to connect to a port on eth0 IPs of the instances and I would like to make the three instances to communicate with each other on eth1 interface IP. Is there a way that this is possible.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the subnets are part of the same VPC, then you just need to setup the Security Group on each instance to allow communication.

If the subnets are part of different VPCs then you will have to use vPC peering or a VPN.